# Does anyone know why making 1000s of small Labels takes so long? Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, time, label

Does anyone know why printing the contents of a 100x100 matrix using Labels takes so long? Below is an example. I am also open to any alternative ideas.

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except:
    from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

dbnm = Tk()
a = np.zeros([100,100])
for i, ii in enumerate(a):
    for j, k in enumerate(ii):
        Label(dbnm, text = '  ', k, '  ').grid(row=i,column=j)

dbnm.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice, and so are bare `except` statements, be careful!

Comment: You are creating 100x100 (i.e 10000) labels, not 1000.  And `tkinter` is not a high performance library.

Comment: There is a 's' on that 1000 in the title.... Either way, does "not a high-performance library" mean that there is no way to print large grids you can scroll around in with Tkinter?

Comment: Instead of creating 10000 separate widgets, it would be nice to have one scrollable table widget. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Tkinter, but In PyQt you could do this easily with QTableWidget. I recommend learning PyQt anyway, it's much better than Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because tkinter isn't designed to make 10,000 widgets. `grid` has to do a fair number calculations for every cell. Doing those calculations 10,000 times adds up. Even switching to `place` where you explicitly put each cell at a specific location is going to be very slow.

If you draw text on a canvas rather than using labels and `grid` it will perform orders of magnitude faster, but at 10,000 text items even the canvas will start to bog down.